# Need Help in TCL

Tags: tcl

```
% set j 1
1

% set a [list $j]
1

% set a [list {$j}]
{$j}

% set a "$j"
1

% set a "[list {$j}]"
{$j}
```

Here in this case what is the exact difference between `""` and `[list]`? Why is the `j` value in the last case not substituted as the it starts with (quotes)? And why is `j` value not substituted in `% set a [list {$j}]` case? I am really confused regarding this.

Comment: What you need help with first is how to devise effective titles for SO questions

Comment: You need to read through the [Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could read this [book extract](http://beedub.com/book/3rd/Tclintro.pdf) which talks about what you are asking here.

Basically, it talks about grouping and the different substitutions in Tcl, which I think is really what will make you understand what you're asking about.

> Here in this case what is the exact difference between "" and [list]?

Your question is vague. If you're asking what the exact difference between `set a [list {$j}]` and `set a "[list {$j}]"`, I would say that there is no difference. In both cases, the variable `a` is being set to the list you defined.

Quotes are used to group words together to form one argument. Your code would have been different if you had:

```
set a This list contains: [list {$j}]
```

and

```
set a "This list contains: [list {$j}]"
```

The first line is giving the variable `a` 4 arguments, namely: `This`, `list`, `contains:` and `[list {$j}]` but this will give you an error since `set` takes only two parameters at most, one being the variable name and the other being the value of the variable.

The second line is giving `a` a single variable grouped by quotes `"This list contains: [list {$j}]"` The quotes will allow command substitution so that the command `list` is executed and the returned value given to the variable `a`.

> Why is the `j` value in the last case not substituted as the it starts with (quotes)? And why is `j` value not substituted in `% set a [list {$j}]` case?

The innermost grouping is `{$j}` and braces prevent any form of substitution to take place. What happens is that you first get `"[list {$j}]"` and Tcl evaluates the command: `[list {$j}]`. The first element of the list is an unsubstituted string `$j`, so that `list` returns `$j` and not the value of the variable `j`.

To make the list return the value of the variable `j`, simply remove the braces:

```
set a "[list $j]"
```

And since `[list $j]` is the only thing in the quotes, you can drop the quotes to yield the same results.

```
set a [list $j]
```

Note that elements of a list are often returned wrapped around braces:

```
% puts [list "item 1" "item 2"]
{item 1} {item 2}
```

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
% puts [list {item 1} {item 2}]
{item 1} {item 2}
```

Because there are no substitutions to be performed. But!

```
% set a "item 1"
item 1
% set b "item 2"
item 2
% puts [list "$a" "$b"]
{item 1} {item 2}
% puts [list $a $b]
{item 1} {item 2}
% puts [list {$a} {$b}]
{$a} {$b}
% puts [list "$a $b"]
{item 1 item 2}
% puts [list {$a $b}]
{$a $b}
```

I think that this should be simple enough to show how substitution and grouping work in Tcl. If you apply what I have explained, it should be easy to understand why each of the above happens.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation . but i want to know the difference between the following 2 statements .                                % set a "1 2 3 4"

1 2 3 4

% set a [list 1 2 3 4]  
1 2 3 4

%

Comment: @user For those _specific_ statements, there's no difference. Replace `1` with `$xyz` and you may observe differences if that variable contains a compound value.